# my duck is clearly having a no bones day

Tags: modeling, animation, bones

blend file: https://ufile.io/ctrr9liu

I have animated the bones and everything looked good in the viewport display when previewing the animation, but when I started rendering the animation, the bone animation seems to be lagging. You can see the hat is still in motion. The hat it parented to 3 vertices on the duck's head, so if the head wasn't actually moving, then the hat wouldn't be moving alone in the rendered GIF. Has anyone seen this issue before. The first GIF is the viewport, and you can see what it's supposed to do. And in the second GIF is that which rendered before I stopped it after I noticed the issue.

[image]
[image]

Comment: hello, plase share your file

Comment: Check if the hat as object has some unwanted keyframes or constraints (maybe you left the autokeyframe record button enabled during setup scene).

Comment: @moonboots sorry it was late, and I forgot to add it in. I didn't unsubdivide the duck cause it messed with the clean lines between eye and beak with the white part of the duck.

Comment: @joshsanfelici I did leave the keyframe button on but after turning it off and rendering the same frames to see if it helped it made not change. The hat is parented to an empty that is parented to points on the head. The animation plays right in the viewport still, but the bone animation lags in rendering.

Comment: Now, I did test something out that is weird. I looked through the rendered animation images for an obvious image that was messed up and decided to just render that one frame instead of render animation. Now what's odd is that when I did just the single frame, it matched with what the viewport showed. The head was in the right place and not lagging behind. Why is that, maybe. Could it be not the bones that is the issue but something with the rendering animation. I don't really want to manually save each frame myself just to have the rig animate properly.

Comment: It works fine for me, I've tested a render in Eevee as PNG at 30% of the real dimension

Comment: But I'm using cycles. I don't understand eevee and I hate how eevee looks with my models and lighting looks weird.

Comment: there should be no difference between EEVEE and Cycles for animation, so if it works in EEVEE, it should work in Cyles, _unless_ you're animating shaders in a way I can't imagine.  In future, you might consider using blend-exchange for your blend files, as it has a relatively fast download for free. ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Comment: On my end the duck doesn't animate at all, because it has no weights. Not even vertex groups. So I wonder how that happens if you all have moving ducks in the first place. Besides, I see you are animating with Rigify's metarig, You shouldn't. The metarig is a placement tool to generate the actual animation rig, it is not supposed to be used for animation.

Comment: @MartyFouts that's what I thought, the animation would be the same in either eevee or cycles. But I'm noticing I'm having a different issue when rendering a different animation and this time there are no bones, it's just animating location and rotation. Objects aren't showing in some random frames sometimes, and sometimes that will appear. I'm not animating shaders with the duck. It's just the bones and the empty that the hat is parented to. You don't need to send a how-to for uploading a blend file. I know how and last big file I tried was too big to work, and this one is 154.5mb.

Comment: @L0Lock when I parented the mesh to the bones, I did automatic weights. I don't know what rigify metarig is, but after I parented the bones and duck, I went into pose mode and just rotated each bone I wanted throughout the timeline to make the duck animate. Is that not how you animate the bones. If not, pls send me a video properly explaining what you are suggesting I should do next time I want to animate bones. I seriously thought that's how you animate the bones.

Comment: It sounds correct, but for some reason the file I download is as if you never done that. Parenting an armature with automatic weights would add an "Armature Deform" modifier to the selected meshes, as well as creating and populating vertex groups for each deform bone found in the armature. There is none of that in the blend file I get, so either there's something wrong on your side or there's a data loss during download somehow. But If I redo it, your animation renders fine: https://i.imgur.com/glOzLkR.gif See some Rigify tutorials, like this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fUqD-54QESY

Comment: Also, 154MB is excessive for what we need to help you, you have several 8k texture files and the "QuickStitch" mesh alone is two billion triangles, that is way overkill for what you're doing with it. When you seek help on the web, maybe don't include such heavy unrelated data, or use lighter ones. And use the Compress option when saving the file, it helps a bit.